# Reduce logging output of Postgres Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, logging

If you run

```
docker run --rm postgres
```

You get:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

****************************************************
WARNING: No password has been set for the database.
         This will allow anyone with access to the
         Postgres port to access your database. In
         Docker's default configuration, this is
         effectively any other container on the same
         system.

         Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set
         it in "docker run".
****************************************************
waiting for server to start....2018-06-09 06:11:42.530 UTC [39] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-06-09 06:11:42.543 UTC [40] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-06-09 06:11:42 UTC
2018-06-09 06:11:42.552 UTC [39] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
ALTER ROLE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

2018-06-09 06:11:42.665 UTC [39] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2018-06-09 06:11:42.668 UTC [39] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2018-06-09 06:11:42.669 UTC [39] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 46) exited with exit code 1
2018-06-09 06:11:42.672 UTC [41] LOG:  shutting down
2018-06-09 06:11:42.687 UTC [39] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2018-06-09 06:11:42.776 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2018-06-09 06:11:42.776 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2018-06-09 06:11:42.780 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-06-09 06:11:42.791 UTC [57] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-06-09 06:11:42 UTC
2018-06-09 06:11:42.800 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

63 log lines of startup info, not to mention all the additional verbosity when you start executing queries against it. This is great info, but when you're constantly starting up and destroying the same containers over and over again in local development, it's noise.

---

How can I "quiet" these logs? I don't want to get rid of them entirely... I still want to see critical errors or severe warnings. I also still want them directed to `stdout` and `stderr`, not a separate file or as a detached process.

Ideally I'm looking for an environment variable I can configure, but I haven't had much luck finding one in the documentation for the images. I had a similar problem with the official RabbitMQ image and was able to get it to be significantly quieter with this:

```
RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS=-rabbit log [{console,[{level,warning}]}]
```

I'm looking for something similar I can do with the official [Postgres images](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

Comment: I didn't find any flag to change logging level in this image. Either you can run this docker container in detached mode. docker run -d <image>
Or you can build your custom image over this official image after changing log level manually.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an Environment Variable, but you can set logging options using a configuration file instead.

```
docker run -i --rm postgres:12.1 cat /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample > my-postgres.conf
echo "log_min_messages = error" >> my-postgres.conf
docker run --rm postgres -v "$PWD/my-postgres.conf":/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf postgres -c 'config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf'
```